# Best telescope for value per dollar?

Tags: resource-recommendations, astronomy, telescopes

recently I'm thinking of buying a telescope for recreational purposes. I'm looking for telescopes that have the highest performance/cost ratio, and I'm willing to spend around $200 on this.

Anyone have good recommendations?

PS. I live in Berkeley, is it a good place to look at stars?

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for our Q&A site on Physics because it's a shopping request and not really a question about physics or astronomy.

Comment: It's almost New Moon, so if you have clear skies today, you can [read this article](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-resources/light-pollution-and-astronomy-the-bortle-dark-sky-scale/) and then go outside to test how dark the sky is in Berkeley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [The Best Cheap Budget Telescopes Under $200](http://telescopeobserver.com/best-telescope-under-200-dollars/); this presents the latest list of all affordable telescopes that are competent for beginners. Also you can check [The cheap telescopes of 2014](http://telescopeobserver.com/the-best-telescope-reviews-2014/). Remember always that though *magnification* is good, but you must need to have a good apparture in your device & for that I prefer [Newtonian telescopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_telescope) or in general a reflecting telescope. You can check [Choosing a telescope: A Beginner’s Guide](http://www.ozscopes.com.au/choosing-a-telescope.html) for more info on what basis you should buy your device.